# JBoss as5, JVM_Bind address

Tags: jboss, jvm, bind

This may have been addressed prior, but I don't see a question specifically from this problem.
I'm trying to run 3 separate instances of JBoss as5 on my Win7 box. After starting the initial server the subsequent server startups complain:

```
13:57:59,659 ERROR [RmiInitialization]
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 0; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

which would indicate to me that the JVM_Bind port is not getting configured so it's defaulting to 0 ?

If so, where/how should this be defined in the JBoss infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the same bind address. Please do an nslookup or lsof to check your address and port. You could also set a port offset since your instances are running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try **stopping services** in `services.msc` particular to other application servers like   `IBM Websphere`.